# Реализация Server Side для android

Tags: java

Всем привет.

Пишу Hello World! на андроид и java на сокетах.

Приложение с андроида через Интернет шлет в виртуалку(CentOS) на моём компьютере введенный текст. Все работает, но вопрос не в этом.
 На сервере я скомпилировал java код и запустил на выполнение через команду java + Имя класса. Что то мне подсказывает, что в реальности так не делают). 
 Какие технологии используют для серверов на java для андроид приложений? Это должны быть сервлеты или что?

Я понимаю, что вопрос может быть из разряда "погугли", но я гуглил и пока картина в голове не рисуется. К сожалению.

Help.

Comment: Что представляет собой серверное приложение сейчас?

Comment: android тут не при чем. Сервер сайд одинаковый для всего

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Отметил. Спасибо за подсказку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем скажу так, писать сервер что для android приложений, что для чего-либо другого абсолютно неважно, главное выбрать протокол для общения и формат хранения данных. Вы будете общаться скорее всего по http. В качестве формата хранения данных выбирайте между xml, json (это наверное предпочтительней), ну может быть что-то своё придумаете. 
Тут скорее всего нужно гуглить Java REST API. Почитайте про [spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). Почитайте про веб-серверы, например [tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/). Узнаете как на java пишутся веб-приложения. Тогда и поймёте. Можно вообще на python писать веб-сервер. Это неважно. Проще всего писать веб-приложения на php или python, на java будет посложнее.

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь. Особенно помог этот коммент. Понятно теперь в какую сторону двигаться. Чего то я сомневался, что сообщение передаётся по http. Сейчас прояснилось.

Answer (score 3):

Если у Вас собственное серверное решение на сокетах, то никакой сервер приложений не нужен. Запускайте себе Ваш сервер из коммандной строки или каким-нить скриптом, это вполне себе решение.
Другое дело, что "идеологически" было бы правильно построить сервер REST API и использовать его любым клиентом на любой платформе.
Все зависит от задачи.